# Matrix decomposition

Tags: sas, matrix-decomposition

I have a symmetric matrix $V$ of order 10. I want to decompose $V$ in such a way that $$V=SS'$$ with $S$ being non triangular.  The matrix $S$ has some restrictions that 45 cells have ‘0’ values and 55 other remaining cells are supposed to be solved.

I am looking for solving this using sas.

Here is the structure of $S$ matrix (all 1's are to be replaced by variables; 55 variables and 45 zeros)
 $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks Glen. I would require this while implementing SVAR (structural VAR) restrictions.

Comment: Is the pattern of zeros such that permutations of the rows and/or columns could yield a triangular matrix? (I think it's sufficient if there are rows and columns that have no zeros, 1 zero, ... 9 zeros)

Comment: The pattern of restriction in S is such that, we cant make it in form of triangular matrix. Had  it been triangular one we would have used Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: What sort of pattern *do* you have?

Comment: @Glen_b I have added the pattern of restrictions in the question.

Comment: I don't really know the best way to do this.  But you've got 55 variables and 55 equations.  You should be able to set up a linear system and just solve for all the nonzero elements of $S$.  It will be a pain to set up and it will be dog slow.  But assuming there is a solution, it should get the job done.